# Why O_DIRECT is slower than normal read?

Tags: c, linux, io

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int fd;
    int alignment = 4096;
    int bufsize = 4096 * 4096;
    char* buf = (char*) memalign(alignment, bufsize);
    int i, n, result=0;
    const char* fname = "1GB.txt";

    if ((fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY|O_DIRECT)) < 0) {
        printf("%s: cannot open %s\n", fname);
        exit(2);
    }

    while ( (n = read(fd,buf,bufsize)) > 0 )
        for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
            result += buf[i];
    
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the command I'm running:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
time ./a.out 1GB.txt
```

Without O_DIRECT and after flushing page cache it takes only 1.1 seconds, with O_DIRECT it takes 2.5 seconds.

I tried changing the alignment and bufsize. Increasing the bufsize to `4096 * 4096 * 4` reduced the running time to 1.79 seconds. Increasing bufsize to `4096 * 4096 * 64` reduced running time to 1.75 seconds. Reducing the alignment to 512 reduced the running time to 1.72 seconds. I don't know what else to try.

I don't understand why using O_DIRECT makes the code slower. Could it be due to the fact that I'm using disk encryption?

I'm on Debian 12 kernel 6.1.0-9-amd64

UPDATE: Follow up: [Why O_DIRECT is slower than plain read() even with read-ahead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76594891/why-o-direct-is-slower-than-plain-read-even-with-read-ahead)

Comment: Not sure, but i assume, when `O_DIRECT` is not set, the kernel is reading ahead while you are processing the data. In case it is set, the kernels waits for the call, reads `bufsize` bytes, stops the reading and returns the syscall. If it is not set, the kernel doesn't need to stop the reading and can fill up a cache in case you need it, so when you do the next `read` syscall, part of the reading is already done. If there is enough RAM to spare, the kernel may use it for such optimization. You could fill up your RAM with other applications to test that.

Comment: Did you try `mmap()`-ing the file? Maybe this could enhance speed (maybe not and is much slower, but you have to test it).

Comment: If you want to use `O_DIRECT` you could start a second process with shared memory, containign 2 buffers. One process (A) fills up buffer 0, informs the other process (B) about it and fills up buffer 1, while process B is working with the data in buffer 0, when Process B is done with buffer 0 it informs process A. When process A is finished filling buffer 1, it informs process B and waits till process B has finished buffer 0 (if not already done) and then fills up buffer 0 .... (you get the idea, hopefully).

Comment: Hi, the `mmap()` version (with and without O_DIRECT) took about 1.2-1.3 seconds compared to read() which took about 1.1 seconds. Note that `mmap` is faster when the file is in the page cache, but it is slower when the file is not in the page cache.

Comment: Note that [the manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) says of `O_DIRECT` that "In general this will degrade performance", so it should be no surprise that that's indeed what you observe.

Comment: *I don't understand why using O_DIRECT makes the code slower. Could it be due to the fact that I'm using disk encryption?*  Absolutely that could remove any performance improvement from using direct IO.  Depending on how the disk encryption is done, it can literally prevent direct access while bypassing the page cache.  So all you did might have done was turn off read-ahead by using `O_DIRECT`.  There's a reason why high-end databases and other applications use direct IO, even on Linux, Linus Torvald's rants against it notwithstanding.

Comment: @JohnBollinger In this case, though, direct IO should be faster.  It's a simple read-once.  Given that it actually worked with a 512-byte aligned buffer per the OP's "Reducing the alignment to 512 reduced the running time to 1.72 seconds" I suspect direct IO wasn't actually used.  IME with direct IO on Linux, it fails if the buffer isn't page-aligned.  No one has addressed **"Could it be due to the fact that I'm using disk encryption?"** yet.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, 1.72 seconds is still much slower than the 1.1 seconds the OP observed without O_DIRECT. I don't dispute that disk encryption might be playing a role here, but I don't see any reason to think that any of the OP's tests failed to use direct I/O.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The man page states merely "Try to minimize cache effects..."  If the encryption were to prevent actual use of direct IO while still bypassing read-ahead, that would explain the results.  The OP could verify that by using a buffer **known** to be non-page aligned and see if that fails.  (It occurs to me that the buffer returned from a `memalign()` call for 512-byte-aligned large buffer is likely to be page-aligned...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Linus summarizes `O_DIRECT` pretty well in [this old mailing list thread](https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/o_direct.html), where someone was experiencing the same problem you are:

> On Fri, 10 May 2002, Lincoln Dale wrote:
>
> > so O_DIRECT in 2.4.18 still shows up as a 55% performance hit versus no
> > O_DIRECT. anyone have any clues?
>
> Yes.
>
> O_DIRECT isn't doing any read-ahead.
>
> For O_DIRECT to be a win, you need to make it asynchronous.

> The thing that has always disturbed me about O_DIRECT is that the whole
> interface is just stupid, and was probably designed by a deranged monkey
> on some serious mind-controlling substances [*].
>
> It's simply not very pretty, and it doesn't perform very well either
> because of the bad interfaces (where synchronicity of read/write is part
> of it, but the inherent page-table-walking is another issue).
>
> I bet you could get *better* performance more cleanly by splitting up the
> actual IO generation and the "user-space mapping" thing sanely.

So you're experiencing slower read operations because no read-ahead nor caching is being performed, which is the normal behavior without `O_DIRECT`.

Unless you want to request reading a much larger size, if you do chunked reads, you can really only benefit from `O_DIRECT` if you are implementing asynchronous operations, for example using [`io_uring`](https://manned.org/io_uring.7). Other interesting solutions are also suggested by Linus in the mailing list thread linked above.

Comment: Linus is waaay off base here.  "For O_DIRECT to be a win, you need to make it asynchronous." is bullhockey,  Read large chunks, maybe even using multiple threads, so read-ahead doesn't matter, and skipping the page cache will improve performance.  As long as you're only reading the data *once*.  or you're reading so much data any re-read will be flushed from the cache anyway.  The "deranged monkey" is the Linux implementation - where even simple calls like `pwrite()` are fundamentally broken because of the implementation.  On Solaris, direct IO is 20-30% faster, and sanely implemented.

Comment: IDK, I would consider a 4MiB buffer moderately large to be honest. But yeah, the Linux implementation is definitely a big *meh*.

Comment: Agreed.  I posted that comment before noticing the OP is using disk encryption of an unknown type.  I'm strongly suspecting that could be having an impact by adding significant latency to each `read()` call, which combined with with `O_DIRECT` disabling read-ahead slows things down.

Comment: Actually OP's buffer is 16MiB (4096 * 4096), I'm bad at math.

Comment: You're right. I write a multithreaded version of the program and it is just as fast as the fread() version! See: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/285844/can-my-multithreaded-o-direct-file-read-and-process-program-be-faster

Comment: Hey @MarcoBonelli, just wanted to say thank you for mentioning io_uring. I'm trying that now and I'm getting very incredible speed gains. Thank you.