# Why O_DIRECT is slower than plain read() even with read-ahead?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, file-io

This is a followup on this question: [Why O_DIRECT is slower than normal read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76533640/why-o-direct-is-slower-than-normal-read)

I followed the recommendation in the answer to my question and implemented read-ahead using a separate thread, but the O_DIRECT version is still slower than the non-O_DIRECT version. Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

#define BUFSIZE 134217728

// globals
std::mutex mut;
unsigned char* buffers[12]; // global array of pointers to buffers where file will be read
int bytes_read[12] = {0};
std::condition_variable cv;
// write_head is the shared variable associated with cv
int write_head = 0; // index of buffer currently being written to

void producer_thread()
{
    int fd;
    const char* fname = "1GB.txt";

    if ((fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY|O_DIRECT)) < 0) {
        printf("%s: cannot open %s\n", fname);
        exit(2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i){
        unsigned char* buf = buffers[i];
        int n = read(fd,buf,BUFSIZE);
        bytes_read[i] = n;
        // wake up consumer thread
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
            write_head = i + 1;
        }
        cv.notify_all();

        if ( n == 0 ){ // if we have reached end of file
            std::cout << "Read to end of file" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Buffers used: " << i << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }
}


void consumer_thread(){
    unsigned long result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i){
        // wait for buffer to become available for reading
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
            cv.wait(lk, [&]() { return i < write_head; });
        }
        int n = bytes_read[i];
        if ( n == 0 ) {
            std::cout << "Result: " << result;
            return ;
        }
        // now process the data
        unsigned char* buf = buffers[i];
        for (int j=0; j<n; ++j)
            result += buf[j];
    }
}


int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::duration;
    using std::chrono::milliseconds;

    puts("Allocating buffers");
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    int alignment = 4096;
    
    // allocate 10 buffers and put them into the global buffers array
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        unsigned char* buf = (unsigned char*) memalign(alignment, BUFSIZE);
        buffers[i] = buf;
    }
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    /* Getting number of milliseconds as a double. */
    duration<double, std::milli> ms_double = end - start;
    puts("finished allocating buffers");
    std::cout << "time taken: " << ms_double.count() << "ms\n";

    // start producer and consumer threads
    std::thread t1(producer_thread), t2(consumer_thread);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the commands I used:

```
g++ fsum.cpp -O3
free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
time ./a.out
```

For the non-O_DIRECT version, I simply deleted O_DIRECT from the source code above and recompiled.

Every measurement was run after flushing the page cache as shown above.

Here are my results:

```
O_DIRECT: 0.810s, 0.811s, 0.722s, 0.818s, 0.669s
non-O_DIRECT: 0.666s, 0.754s, 0.615s, 0.634s, 0.634s
```

Looks like the non-O_DIRECT version is consistently around 0.1-0.2s faster than the O_DIRECT version. Literally the only difference is that the file is opened with O_DIRECT in the O_DIRECT version and not with O_DIRECT in the non-O_DIRECT version - everything else is the same.

Is read-ahead still the problem? Maybe the Linux read-ahead is more efficient than the read-ahead I implemented?

UPDATE: I've attached the iostat logs below:

```
root@x:~/test# g++ fsum2.cc -O3
root@x:~/test# iostat
Linux 6.1.0-9-amd64 (x)     01/07/23    _x86_64_    (16 CPU)

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
dm-0              0.93       183.61         4.90       457.03  190635797    5089164  474519964
dm-1              0.93       183.61         4.90       457.03  190632469    5089164  474519964
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00         0.00       2296          0          0
nvme0n1           1.30       183.62         4.90       457.93  190649314    5089166  475449288

root@x:~/test# time ./a.out 
Allocating buffers
time taken0.077616ms
finished allocating buffers
Read to end of file
Buffers used: 8Result: 0
real    0m0.737s
user    0m0.100s
sys 0m0.141s

root@x:~/test# iostat
Linux 6.1.0-9-amd64 (x)     01/07/23    _x86_64_    (16 CPU)

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
dm-0              0.93       184.55         4.90       457.03  191613521    5089196  474519964
dm-1              0.93       184.55         4.90       457.03  191610193    5089196  474519964
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00         0.00       2296          0          0
nvme0n1           1.31       184.56         4.90       457.92  191627038    5089198  475449288

root@x:~/test# nano fsum2.cc 
root@x:~/test# g++ fsum2.cc -O3
root@x:~/test# free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
root@x:~/test# iostat
Linux 6.1.0-9-amd64 (x)     01/07/23    _x86_64_    (16 CPU)

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
dm-0              0.93       184.57         4.90       456.96  191660405    5090008  474519964
dm-1              0.93       184.57         4.90       456.96  191657077    5090008  474519964
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00         0.00       2296          0          0
nvme0n1           1.31       184.58         4.90       457.86  191673922    5090010  475449288

root@x:~/test# time ./a.out 
Allocating buffers
time taken0.027392ms
finished allocating buffers
Read to end of file
Buffers used: 8Result: 0
real    0m0.614s
user    0m0.089s
sys 0m0.246s

root@x:~/test# iostat
Linux 6.1.0-9-amd64 (x)     01/07/23    _x86_64_    (16 CPU)

Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
dm-0              0.94       185.51         4.90       456.96  192639133    5090024  474519964
dm-1              0.93       185.51         4.90       456.96  192635805    5090024  474519964
dm-2              0.00         0.00         0.00         0.00       2296          0          0
nvme0n1           1.31       185.52         4.90       457.85  192652650    5090026  475449288
```

Comment: If your buffer size doesn't match the block size of the device then you'll probably get worse performance with `O_DIRECT`

Comment: Have you looked at iostat to see the actual size of file I/Os performed?

Comment: @stark I've attached the iostat outputs. I'm not sure what I should be looking for in the iostat output. The change in kB_read looks about the same for both the O_DIRECT (first run) and the non-O_DIRECT (second run) versions.

Comment: Read it [tag:C] -  C is distinct from C++ and it should not be combined with the C++ tag without a specific reason.

Comment: 130+MB is an awfully large buffer.  Does it really need to be that big?

Comment: @PaulSanders with the amount of RAM in today's computers, 130MB is just a drop in the bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was because I was using disk encryption.

On my current system (the same as the previous system except without disk encryption - I literally just reinstalled the OS with the same options except without disk encryption this time) I'm getting a median of 0.389s for non-O_DIRECT and 0.369s for O_DIRECT. So O_DIRECT made the program faster on my current system (which doesn't have disk encryption), but it made the program slower on my previous system (which used disk encryption).

I don't know why though.